# How to remove a specific data from an API?

Tags: php, api

I'm working on a site which gives metrics of site, it uses API of gtmetrix. So i want to remove a specific data from the coming result but I just dont know how to do it. Some help would be appreciated!

```
    <?php
  require_once('service.inc.php');

  $test = new Services_WTF_Test("email", "api_key");
  $url_to_test = "https://google.me/";
  echo "Testing $url_to_test\n";
  $testid = $test->test(array(
    'url' => $url_to_test
));
if ($testid) {
    echo "Test started with $testid\n";
}
else {
    die("Test failed: " . $test->error() . "\n");
}
echo "Waiting for test to finish\n";
$test->get_results();

if ($test->error()) {
  die($test->error());
}
$testid = $test->get_test_id();
echo "Test completed succesfully with ID $testid\n'<br>";
$results = $test->results();
if ($results): ?>
          <?php 
          foreach($results as $result => $data): ?>
        <strong><?php $ukey = strtoupper($result);
        echo $ukey; ?>:</strong>
        <?php echo $data; ?><br><br>
         <?php endforeach; 
       endif; 
?>
```

The Output Is:
 FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_TIME: 1495

PAGE_ELEMENTS: 44

REPORT_URL: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/google.me/BFylJNX3

REDIRECT_DURATION: 0

FIRST_PAINT_TIME: 1495

DOM_CONTENT_LOADED_DURATION:

DOM_CONTENT_LOADED_TIME: 1908

I want to remove the 3rd data from the api REPORT_URL:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip `REPORT_URL` in foreach

```
$ukey = strtoupper( $result );
if( $ukey != 'REPORT_URL' ) {
    echo '<strong>' . $ukey . '</strong>';
    echo $data . '<br><br>';
}
```